# DAX Count function making mistake somewhere

Tags: excel, count, powerpivot, dax

**File:** count.xlsx located on [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Count)

**Software:** MS Excel 2016 Power Pivot

---

I know for fact there are 10,921 rows in EXCEL sheet.

When I create DAX measure `Total_Incidents:=Count(Graffiti[CREATED_DATE])` value comes to `10,921`. I count the CREATED_DATE because there is no NULL value.

There are three statuses, Open, Pending, Closed which are calculated as follows

`Total_Closed:=sumx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Closed"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Closed= 5354`, <- correct

However, Total_Opened is incorrect

`Total_Opened:=sumx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Open"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Opened= 4483` **it is supposed to be 4481**

However Total_Pending is correct

`Total_Pending:=sumx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Pending"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Pending= 75`, <- correct

When I add totals I get 2 more incidents because of Total_Opened

`Total_Calc:=[Total_Closed]+[Total_Opened]+[Total_Pending]`

`Total_Calc= 10923` **<- incorrect, should be 10921**

Why the discrepancy in Total_Opened? Cannot figure this.

[image]

Comment: Which number do you get if you run this: `COUNTA(Graffiti[STATUS])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had originally answered with this:**

"I know you said you count CREATED_DATE because there is no NULL value, but did you check for *blanks* in your CREATE_DATE column? I duplicated your problem by having blank dates. You could have 2 blank dates.

You could use `COUNTBLANK(Graffiti[CREATED_DATE])` to check if you do have blanks."

**Then I noticed you had a link to your Excel file on GitHub**, so...

I downloaded it and I looked for blanks in your dates--there were none.

So I added columns for Total_Closed, Total_Opened, Total_Pending and Total_Calc. *(I used your formulas, but instead of `sumx`, I used `countx` in each formula, so I could just compare row counts.)*

`Total_Incidents:=Count(Graffiti[CREATED_DATE])`

`Total_Closed:=countx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Closed"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Opened:=countx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Open"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Pending:=countx(FILTER(Graffiti,Graffiti[STATUS]="Pending"),[Total_Incidents])`

`Total_Calc:=[Total_Closed]+[Total_Opened]+[Total_Pending]`

Here's what I got:

Total_Incidents: 10921

Total_Closed: 6365

Total_Opened: 4481

Total_Pending: 75

Total_Calc: 10921

These counts look correct.

***I'm guessing you figured out and corrected your problem.***

Comment: Oh .... using `sumx` didn't make sense. It's like taking the sum of all dates (who can take sum of dates?). But now I'm perplexed. What's the difference between sumx and countx if they yielded same result for `Total_Closed` and `Total_Calc`?

Comment: You hadn't summed your dates. You had counted them. You had summed your Total_Incidents. Summing them with sumx added the values in the Total_Incidents column together.  With countx, you count the number of occurrences of those values...basically, you count the rows.

Comment: Thank you @marc-pincince